# 2011 Subaru Impreza (Automatic) Slipping when shifting uphill

Tags: automatic-transmission, subaru, smell, impreza

My car has been having a hard time shifting when I accelerate a lot, mainly when I am driving uphill. It seems like it is slipping. There is also a burning smell from time to time I notice when I have been driving for a bit and park. I checked my transmission fluid and it is full. I used to drive in sport mode quite a bit (because it shifts better) would this cause any problems? Is there any hope that my transmission isn't shot?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did you happen to *smell* the transmission fluid when you inspected it? If not, take a whiff. If it smells burnt, it could just need replaced. If you've never replaced the fluid, it might be a good time to do some maintenance.